# Activating tabs on page load using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, selector

How can i activate the first tab of my web page in page load?
I do the tabs using jquery and *ul* tags.

& after click on individual tab they should be active.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="sociallink">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab1"><img class="sa_image" src="images/facebook.png" border="0" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab2" ><img class="sa_image" src="images/tweeter.png" border="0" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab3" ><img class="sa_image" src="images/message.png" border="0" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tab4" ><img class="sa_image" src="images/persnal.png" border="0" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#sociallink ul li:first').addClass('active');

    $('#sociallink ul li a').click(function(){
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
        return false;
    });
});
```

running this code does not activate the first tab as well as click on other they are not getting activated.

Please help.

Comment: i think your mean in line 4 is : ... $(this).attr('class') ... isn't??

Comment: In your HTML code, you have written `socilalink` instead of `sociallink`.

Comment: i want to open new links onclick function of <a>

Answer (score 0):

you should switch class 'active' between clicked tabs. see below:

```
$('#sociallink ul li a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('li').siblings('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('class');
    return false;
});
```

also it's better to assign attribute `class='tabx'` to it's parent `li`

Answer (score 0):

You have a first tab activated, you need to call the click of the li and add the active class then remove the active from others:

assume this is your active tab css class:

```
.active a{
    border:solid 1px red;
}
```

then use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    $('#sociallink ul li:first').addClass('active');

    $('#sociallink ul li a').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Your css class for `.active{}` is required to see how this is going to affect the active tab.

Or even you can try this one:

```
    $('#sociallink ul li').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        return false;
    });
```